# Unable to log in as root or domain user

Tags: debian-jessie, winbind

**Solved** - See Update 2 below.

We have a Debian Jessie DNS / SSH server.

I have joined it to our AD domain by following [this guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_8&p=samba&f=3) and created a cron job to sync the time with a domain controller using ntp. Additionally, I have put the AD group "sudoers" into `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`.

This setup has worked just fine for a few months. Authorized domain users could log in with SSH and those who were members of the sudoers AD group could use sudo.

**Suddenly domain users as well as root can no longer log in.** Local user accounts except root still work. <del>However, sudo no longer works.</del>

When trying to log in as root or use su I get "No logon servers".

```
su -
Password:
No logon servers
su: authentification error
```

<del>I am now stuck without root access.</del> I can use sudo now - see update below.

<del>Appending "single" and/or "init=/bin/bash" to the grub2 boot entry leaves me with an <del>*unresponsive* shell:</del></del>

**Update:**
A PS/2 keyboard got the single user root shell working which allowed me to explicitly add my local user to the sudoers file. I now have root access in multi-user.

However, the login problem is still not fixed. Any ideas?

**Update 2:**
DNS was incorrectly configured. Instead of querying itself (it is the primary domain DNS server) the server tried to get the DC address from 8.8.8.8... duh. Edited /etc/resolv.conf and everything magically works.

Comment: /etc/nsswitch.conf problem?

Comment: @mdpc Thank you for your comment. Here's my [nsswitch.conf](https://tillvonelling.ddns.net/owncloud/index.php/s/kgtb218ABkEbEgW). I guess `myhostname` should be replaced with the actual hostname?